# Compare two number SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, common-table-expression

In SQL,I am trying to compare two numbers in the same field. Both numbers contain different information, but for some technical reason they are same. The problem is when exist one sub-string of  length 5 and another of length 4 and the last 4 digits of both are same.I want to get the first one with length 5.

Example:

```
--------------------------------
|ID | Number| Description        |
---------------------------------
| 1 | 12345 | Project X,Ready    |
---------------------------------
| 2 |  2345 | Project X,onDesign |
---------------------------------
```

I should always get 12345(or biggest one) if exist numbers with last 4 digits same. Is there any CASE or CTE statement which can give me an easy resolution for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Can you please post the output you're trying to get for this sample input? Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: You want to select biggest value?

Comment: What is the type of Number column?

Comment: is **INT**@giorgi-nakeuri

Comment: @FManin You can check out my solution. And please share the execution time, i.e which query is faster in getting the proper result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id
,Number
,Description
FROM (
SELECT Id
    ,Number
    ,Description
    ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY right(cast([Number] AS VARCHAR(20)), 4) ORDER BY Number DESC) AS Ranking
FROM YourTable
) InnerTable
WHERE ranking = 1
```

Comment: Thanks it was exactly what we were looking for @AndrejSkripic

Answer (score 1):

So you need to join using last 4 digits. You could do this by using simple `MOD` operator. It's used as a percentage sign in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 12345 % 10000;
```

This outputs `2345`. Exactly what we are looking for.

So we could build the following query to use that calculation:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    ID INT
    , Number INT
    , Description VARCHAR(500)
);

INSERT INTO @Test(ID, Number, Description)
VALUES (1, 12345, 'Project X,Ready')
    , (2, 2345, 'Project X,onDesign');

SELECT T1.*
FROM @Test AS T1
INNER JOIN @Test AS T2
    ON T2.Number = T1.Number % 10000
WHERE T2.Number <> T1.Number;
```

Output:

```
╔════╦════════╦═════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Number ║   Description   ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║  12345 ║ Project X,Ready ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Note that I've added `WHERE T2.Number <> T1.Number`. It eliminates equal numbers, because `SELECT 2345 % 10000` is `2345` as well.

#### Update

This could be done using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH Data (ID, Number, Description, RN)
AS (
    SELECT ID
        , Number
        , Description
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number % 10000 ORDER BY Number DESC)
    FROM @Test
    )
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This will do the classic row_number stuff. It will partition windows by `Number % 10000`, which means that 12345 and 2345 will fall under same window and the highest number will always come first.

Comment: It is working properly to avoid the biggest number. But what about if when we don't have the biggest number, should display the small one. @Evaldas

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `not exists`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Number INT ,
      Description VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 12345, 'Project 1' ),
        ( 2, 2345, 'Project 2' ),
        ( 3, 77777, 'Project 3' ),
        ( 4, 7777, 'Project 4' ),
        ( 5, 88888, 'Project 5' ),
        ( 6, 9999, 'Project 6' )

SELECT * FROM @t t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @t t2 
                 WHERE t2.ID <> t1.ID AND 
                 CAST(t2.Number AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE '%' + CAST(t1.Number AS VARCHAR(10)))
```

Output:

```
ID  Number  Description
1   12345   Project 1
3   77777   Project 3
5   88888   Project 5
6   9999    Project 6
```

Comment: This shold work, but as far as I know we should avoid using sub query since its slower than JOIN. What you say @Giorgi?

Comment: @J19, I can only say that you should check generated execution plans for both and see the difference. My solution will work if you have for example 12345 2345 345 and you need to exclude 2 rows. Also my solution works not only on numbers with 5 and 4 length. So choose any answer that is most close to your need :)

Answer (score 0):

The query might be RDBMS spesific. For example with MSSQL you can do like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    myTable AS d1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   myTable AS d2
                     WHERE  SUBSTRING(d2.number, 2, 4) = d1.number );
```

EDIT: Ah, you edited and it is an INT! Then you can use the % operator instead of substring.

Sample with CTE:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE
  (
    id INT IDENTITY
           PRIMARY KEY ,
    number INT ,
    [description] VARCHAR(20)
  );

INSERT  @dummy ( [number], [description] )
VALUES  ( 12345, 'P' ),
        ( 22345, 'P' ),
        ( 2345, 'P' ),
        ( 3456, 'P' ),
        ( 13456, 'P' ),
        ( 4567, 'P' );

WITH  d AS (
             SELECT MAX(number) AS maxNum
             FROM   @dummy AS [d]
             GROUP BY [d].[number] % 10000
           )
  SELECT  d1.*
  FROM    @dummy AS [d1]
  INNER JOIN d ON d.[maxNum] = d1.[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM [Tablename] AS A
INNER JOIN [Tablename] AS B
ON B.Number =RIGHT(A.Number,4)
WHERE B.Number <> A.Number;
```

`RIGHT(A.Number,4)` will compare the last 4 digits and will give the output